# How to chose elliptic curve in RELIC library?

Tags: cryptography, elliptic-curve, relic

RELIC cryptography library is supporting the following pairing curves now. 
`BN_158, BN_254, BN_256, BN_382, BN_446, KSS_508, B12_381, B12_455, B24_477, BN_638, SS_1536`
I got this list from src/fp/relic_fp_param.c. Does RELIC support any pairing curves other than these?
I didn't understand how to select the curve. In order to select `B24_477` curve, should I just it build relic using

```
cmake -DFP-PRIME=477
```

For all these curves, what should I set `BN-PRECI` to? Are there any other parameters that I need to set? Can I chose the pairing curve to use in my code directly?
What happens if I initialize `FP-PRIME` to a number not in the above list?